# Are AppWidgets possible on AndroidTV?

Tags: android, android-tv, android-appwidget

We know that in Android Phones we do have "App-Widgets" which remain in the home screen.

I have tried to run the same mobile app on an Android TV. App works fine but if I do a long tap on the app from list of apps I am not able to see anything options for App-Widgets the same which would be available for Phones/Tablets.

Do we have anything similar as for Android TV? Help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: "We know that in Android Phones we do have "App-Widgets" which remain in the home screen" -- the OS has the capacity to offer app widgets. However, whether any particular *phone* supports app widgets depends on the launcher app used by that phone. There is no requirement for a launcher app to offer app widgets. "Do we have anything similar as for Android TV?" -- Android TV is a particular variant of the Android OS. Whether any given Android TV launcher supports app widgets is up to the developers of that launcher. I would be surprised if many TV launchers support app widgets, though.

Comment: "Whether any given Android TV launcher supports app widgets is up to the developers" -- My app has the code of app widgets and we do support them but still I am not able to see them

Comment: "My app has the code of app widgets" -- based on your question, your app is not the launcher app for that particular Android TV.

Comment: I have been trying this on Android TV Emulator (API-34) which is available in Android Studio

Comment: That, by default, will use a launcher app written by Google. Google chose not to add app widget support. I expect that few launcher apps for Android TV will support app widgets.